# Boostrap tabs not working on codepen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Is there anyone that can help me understand why the tabs within this code are not working on codepen? I enabled bootstrap in codepen settings, but still not working..

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have jquery referenced also, and before the bootstrap reference. 
This is working for me: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaWMxe?editors=1111)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution was adding jquery before not after bootstrap, solved, thank you.